# Describing Types question

Tags: java, types

I have a bunch of types (eg. LargePlane, SmallPlane) that could be in this collection i've made, how do i print like LargePlane? I've tried like typeOf() and stuff but it doesn't work. Within like a toString()? So when i output the collection it states what type it is.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: What language is the question about? It's a blocker to answering the question, actually.

Comment: `instanceof` will work instead of `typeOf()`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.getClass().getName()`

The following example uses a Class object to print the class name of an object:

```
void printClassName(Object obj)
{
     System.out.println("The class of " + obj +
                       " is " + obj.getClass().getName());
}
```

For more details, take a look at [JavaDoc for Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Comment: getSimpleName() is nice, too because you get the class (Plane) name only compared to the fully qualified class name (com.air.Plane etc.) you'll get with getName().

Answer (score 0):

You could either implement an interface or extend something like a "Plane" class

```
public class LargePlane implents IPlane {

  public String toString() {
    // build return string here
  }

}


public interface IPlane {
  public String toString();
}
```